# Get begin poisitions and/or NER from words after parsing

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using the new Stanford CoreNLP NN parser. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
// Sentence to be parsed
String sentence = "This is an example sentence.";

// This is where we store the result from the parser. Initially set to "null".
GrammaticalStructure gs = null;

// Parse the sentence
DocumentPreprocessor tokenizer = new DocumentPreprocessor(new StringReader(sentence));
List<TaggedWord> tagged = null;
for (List<HasWord> sent : tokenizer) {
    tagged = tagger.tagSentence(sent);
    gs = parser.predict(tagged);
}

// Convert the GrammaticalStructure object (the parsing result) into a semantic graph
SemanticGraph semanticGraph = SemanticGraphFactory.generateUncollapsedDependencies(gs);
```

Now, when I iterate over the vertices of `semanticGraph`, I can get the POS tag, but I can't get the NER of the word nor the begin position. So, when I do this:

```
for (IndexedWord vertex : new ArrayList<>(semanticGraph.vertexSet())){
    String tag = vertex.tag();
    String ner = vertex.ner();
    int beginPosition = vertex.beginPosition();
}
```

for `tag` I get the POS tag correctly, for `ner` I get `null` and for `beginPostion` I always get -1.

How can I do the parsing with correctly preserving the begin position of the word in the original string? And if possible, how do I get the NER? (`beginPosition` is actually more important in my case)

Comment: Is there any reason you are avoiding `StanfordCoreNLP pipeline` ?

Comment: No, I just put a simplified version of the code. If you have some suggestion with StanfordCoreNLP pipeline, please post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case NER tags don't exist because you are not actually performing such an annotation in your code. I am not sure why `beginPosition` is not set in the `SemanticGraph`

Using a `StanfordCoreNLP` pipeline is highly recommended for multiple annotations that depend on each other. It's very easy to (re)configure it to use different annotators through a `Properties` object. There is also potential for better performance as it can use multiple threads.

Here is a simple example with a pipeline that keeps the for loop from your code. I have tested (CoreNLP 3.5.2) and both `ner` and `beginPosition` are set correctly. Since no recognizable entities exist in you example sentence `ner` is always `"O"`. Also if you have more than one sentences in your document, you will have to iterate over `sentences` list.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

String sentence = "This is an example sentence.";
Annotation document = new Annotation(sentence);
pipeline.annotate(document);

List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
CoreMap map = sentences.get(0);
SemanticGraph semanticGraph = map.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);

for (IndexedWord vertex : new ArrayList<>(semanticGraph.vertexSet())) {
    String tag = vertex.tag();
    String ner = vertex.ner();
    int beginPosition = vertex.beginPosition();
}
```